# how to get a reference to GLOBALS php variable inside template using Phptal

Tags: template-tal, phptal

Below line

```
tal:attributes="action php:GLOBALS['paypal']['url']"
```

raises:

> PHPTAL_VariableNotFoundException' with message 'Unable to find
>   variable 'GLOBALS' in current scope'

while

```
tal:attributes="action php:GLOBALS['paypal']['url']"
```

works

Comment: I don't see any difference between first and second example. Are you sure you copied that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to rely on globals at all. You should be passing variables to PHPTAL explicitly:

```
$phptal->set('paypal', $GLOBALS['paypal']);
```

and then use `action="${paypal/url}"`

or if you really must:

```
$phptal->set('GLOBALS', $GLOBALS);
```